# Run executeable jar with parameter in tomcat webserver

Tags: java, jsp, jar

Can you give me suggestion how can i run my executable jar with parameter in tomcat server.

It is working fine at local tomcat server but when i upload that in tomcat web server then it is not working.

My code:(inserted into jsp file)

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -version"); 
              process.waitFor();    
        out.print(sen+"<br>"+  process.exitValue()+"<br>");
```

But server does not take any action.

Please can you help me to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat is a java web server where you can load war file. It has a web container so it can process the java web based application with *.war extension. so it will not be able to run jar executable directly, so we will not be able to pass any run time parameter.

Thanks